# Added Objects Are Generated In Much Greater Units Than What Is Preset

Tags: objects, scale, units, dimensions

I am utilizing Blender for 3D Printing purposes and the 3D Printing software uses the metric system (specifically mm and cm). I have already established preset units in the Scene tab:

**Millimeters**

**Length:** Metric

**Angle:** Degrees

**Unit Scale:** 0.0001

Generating a cube results in a cube with the dimensions 20cm x 20cm x 20cm. It appears as if the object generated exceeds the boundary of the scene as you can see from what looks like clipping.

[image]

After some experimentation with the unit scaling value, 20cm (at a Unit Scale of 0.0001) is the smallest I can make the absolute bounding box. If you reduce the unit scale value even further (0.00001) it will default to 2km, the initial value if the unit scale is set to 1.0.

If there are any fixes or add-ons that allow for scaling down to millimeters, I would be grateful.

Comment: you just need to adjust the clip distance for the viewport